# memcached make error: Error1 And Error2

Tags: makefile, memcached, osx-mavericks, processmodel

I was trying to follow this tutorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model

And in the very first step, I wget the file and run the ./configure script.

It complained about missing libevent-

```
➜  memcached-1.4.5  ./configure
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for icc in use... no
checking for Sun cc in use... no
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h usability... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h presence... yes
checking for sasl/sasl.h... yes
checking for gcov... /usr/bin/gcov
checking for main in -lgcov... no
checking for libevent directory... configure: error: libevent is required.
```

After that I did a

```
$ brew install libevent
```

Running the ./configure passed without any error:

```
➜  memcached-1.4.5  ./configure
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for icc in use... no
checking for Sun cc in use... no
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h usability... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h presence... yes
checking for sasl/sasl.h... yes
checking for gcov... /usr/bin/gcov
checking for main in -lgcov... no
checking for libevent directory... (system)
checking for library containing socket... none required
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for library containing umem_cache_create... no
checking for library containing gethugepagesizes... no
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for print macros for integers (C99 section 7.8.1)... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for endianness... little
checking for htonll... no
checking for library containing pthread_create... none required
checking for mlockall... yes
checking for getpagesizes... no
checking for memcntl... no
checking for sigignore... yes
checking for alignment... need
checking for setppriv... no
checking umem.h usability... no
checking umem.h presence... no
checking for umem.h... no
checking for xml2rfc... no
checking for xsltproc... /usr/bin/xsltproc
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

then,

```
➜  memcached-1.4.5  make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in doc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-memcached.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-memcached.Tpo -c -o memcached-memcached.o `test -f 'memcached.c' || echo './'`memcached.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-memcached.Tpo .deps/memcached-memcached.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-hash.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-hash.Tpo -c -o memcached-hash.o `test -f 'hash.c' || echo './'`hash.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-hash.Tpo .deps/memcached-hash.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-slabs.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-slabs.Tpo -c -o memcached-slabs.o `test -f 'slabs.c' || echo './'`slabs.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-slabs.Tpo .deps/memcached-slabs.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-items.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-items.Tpo -c -o memcached-items.o `test -f 'items.c' || echo './'`items.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-items.Tpo .deps/memcached-items.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-assoc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-assoc.Tpo -c -o memcached-assoc.o `test -f 'assoc.c' || echo './'`assoc.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-assoc.Tpo .deps/memcached-assoc.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-thread.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-thread.Tpo -c -o memcached-thread.o `test -f 'thread.c' || echo './'`thread.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-thread.Tpo .deps/memcached-thread.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-daemon.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-daemon.Tpo -c -o memcached-daemon.o `test -f 'daemon.c' || echo './'`daemon.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-daemon.Tpo .deps/memcached-daemon.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-stats.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-stats.Tpo -c -o memcached-stats.o `test -f 'stats.c' || echo './'`stats.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-stats.Tpo .deps/memcached-stats.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-util.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-util.Tpo -c -o memcached-util.o `test -f 'util.c' || echo './'`util.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-util.Tpo .deps/memcached-util.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcached-cache.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-cache.Tpo -c -o memcached-cache.o `test -f 'cache.c' || echo './'`cache.c
mv -f .deps/memcached-cache.Tpo .deps/memcached-cache.Po
gcc  -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls   -o memcached memcached-memcached.o memcached-hash.o memcached-slabs.o memcached-items.o memcached-assoc.o memcached-thread.o memcached-daemon.o memcached-stats.o memcached-util.o memcached-cache.o    -levent
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
make[2]: *** [memcached] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ends up with this error. I haven't ever build anything from source till now so some pointers in how to go about debugging this kind of problem will be helpful. Looking at another post I see the following info maybe helpful:

```
➜  memcached-1.4.5  gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

And my os is mac os x 10.9.2

Thanks and regards,
Dhruv Kapur.

Comment: I have this same issue right now, Can you tell me how to fix this, if u resolve this. @Dhruv Kapur